# Angular Async Router Guards

Tags: angular

We have a Router Guard which checks if a user is logged in and admin
It should also check if a request we send to a server is has the right result.

The problem is the canActivate function is finished before the server request is finished, so the Router Guard is always false.

I hope you have a solution for this problem

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (user != null&&!user.isNotAdmin) {
      if(this.userService.isLoggedIn(user)){
          return true;
      }else{
          return false;
      }
    }else{

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate([''], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: Using a promise with `await` ?

Comment: if possible try to avoid server call in `canActivate`. Because making a server call for every navigation makes your page slow to redirection.

Comment: i have tried but have no idea. How can i do this with await?

Comment: I had the same issue, this thread might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51363905/536388

Comment: You have an object in local storage that just has a key of whether the user is admin — there's absolutely no security to this whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `async/await` to ensure canActivate waits till the resolution of your server request. Here's some sample code to help you:

```js
/* UserService */
isLoggedIn(user): Observable<boolean> {
  // check if user is logged in
  return isUserLoggedIn;
}

/* Guard */
async canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
if (user !== null && !user.isNotAdmin) {

  const isUserLoggedIn: boolean = await this.userService.isLoggedIn(user).toPromise();
  // toPromise() converts Observable to Promise (async/await only works on Promises)
  // the code 'waits' at the above line till the server request is resolved

  return isUserLoggedIn;

} else {
  // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
  this.router.navigate([''], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
}
```

References if you want to read further:

- [async/await documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [es6 key guidelines](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/google-publishes-a-javascript-style-guide-here-are-some-key-lessons-1810b8ad050b)

Answer (score 0):

Later versions of Angular can return an `Observable` from the `canActivate` method, making this much easier. If the user is not found in `localStorage` you return immediately, if a user is found however you call your service method. The `pipe` and `tap` is used to intercept it so to speak, and if it returns `false` it also navigates to `''`.

```js
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<any> {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
  if (user === null || user.isNotAdmin) {
    return false;
  }

  return this.userService.isLoggedIn(user).pipe(
    tap((isLoggedIn) => {
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        this.router.navigate([''], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
      }
    })
  }
}
```

*PS: Checking for admin status from `localStorage` is not very secure, but of course depends on your project whether it is acceptable risk.*